# Destructor in struct and class in c++

Tags: c++

Should I create destructor for this struct? or are there any implicit destructor && will it be destructed when it goes out of scope?

Here both myLogStructure and mySubject are struct type.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef MyLogStruct_H
#define MyLogStruct_H

#include <string>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct mySubject
{
    string Security_ID;
    string Account_Name;
    string Account_Domain;
    string Logon_ID;
};

struct myLogStructure
{
    string message;
    bool isAvailableMySubject;
    mySubject mySubject1;
};
#endif
```

Should I implement destructor for this? or will it be destructed when it goes out of scope?

Here both MyLogStructure and MySubject are class type.
Please note one thing that I have used pointer into this class.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #ifndef MyLogStructure_H
    #define MyLogStructure_H

    #include <string>
    #include "MySubject.h"

    using namespace std;

    class MyLogStructure
    {
    public:
        MyLogStructure(LPWSTR providerMessageString1, int version1);
        ~MyLogStructure(void);
        const wchar_t* message;
        LPWSTR providerMessageString;
        int version;
        bool isAvailableMySubject;
        MySubject*mySubject;
    };
    #endif

    class MySubject
    {
        public:
            MySubject(const wchar_t* Security_ID1, const wchar_t* Account_Name1, const wchar_t* Account_Domain1, const wchar_t* Logon_ID1);
            ~MySubject(void);

            const wchar_t* Security_ID;
            const wchar_t* Account_Name;
            const wchar_t* Account_Domain;
            const wchar_t* Logon_ID;
    };
```

Comment: It depends what your constructors are doing. If your destructor would otherwise be empty `{}` (ie you don't need to delete anything), you can usually omit it entirely.

Comment: To answer the other part of your question, yes objects are destructed when they go out of scope.

Comment: Also whether the type is declared `struct` or `class` has **no** bearing on whether it requires a destructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you need a destructor is *NOT* determined by whether you use a `struct` or `class`. The deciding factor is whether the `struct`/`class` has acquired resources that must be released explicitly when the life of the object ends. If the answer to the question is yes, then you need to implement a destructor. Otherwise, you don't need to implement it.

For the first set of `struct`s, it's best to let the compiler implement the destructors. There is nothing to do in the destructors.

If you implement them, they will be:

```
~mySubject() {}
```

and

```
~myLogStructure() {}
```

You may need to implement destructors in the second set of classes depending on whether you need to release any resources.

Since you have pointers to `w_char` to store that data, you most likely need to implement destructors, and release the memory acquired during the life time of the object.

Comment: should I insert ~mySubject() {} or even is it not needed at all?

Comment: You don't need that at all.

Comment: I have used MySubject as pointer in class type. will it not be problematic?

Comment: If you allocate objects of type `MySubject` using dynamic memory allocation, you need to deallocate them. That still does not make it necessary to explicitly implement a destructor in `MySubject`.

Comment: I use that as follows: outputLog->mySubject = new MySubject(Security_ID, Account_Name, Account_Domain, Logon_ID); here outputLog is a pointer of MyLogStructure. Then is it "resources that must be released explicitly"?

Comment: Then I should release memory hold by mySubject1. correct?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide your own destructors for `mySubject` or `myLogStructure` because the compiler-generated ones will work fine (they will call destructors of `std::string` members).

You do need to provide destructors for `MyLogStructure` and `MySubject` if these classes manage memory which seems to be the case considering members of pointer types.